# Unable to convert base64 from Arraybuffer

Tags: ajax, post, google-drive-api, google-drive-picker

I'm trying to get file from google drive and I'm getting the file contents, converting it to byte array and sending it to backend to save the file on the server(For this I'm using Ajax POST method)

This is what I'm trying to do

// A simple callback implementation.

```
function pickerCallback(data) {
    if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        fileId = data.docs[0].id;
        gapi.load('client', function () {
            gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', function () {
                var file = gapi.client.drive.files.get({ 'fileId': fileId, fields: '*' });
                file.execute(function (resp) {
                    fileext = resp.originalFilename.split('.').pop();
                    inputFileName = randomString(8) + "." + fileext;
                    $('#inputFileName').val(inputFileName);
                    inputFileName = $('#inputFileName').val();
                    fileSize = resp.size;
                    if (fileSize < maxFileSize) {
                        fileId = resp.id;
                        accessToken = oauthToken;
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + '?alt=media', true);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
                        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {//Call a function when the state changes.
                            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                                base64 = base64ArrayBuffer(xhr.response);
                              $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                  url: "googledrive.aspx/GetDriveFile",
                                  data: JSON.stringify({
                                      FileName: inputFileName, Base64: base64
                                  }),
                                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                  dataType: "json",
                                success: function (msg) {
                                    if (msg.d == "true") {
                                       alert("Success");
                                    } else {
                                       alert("Failed");
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function (msg) {
                                    alert(msg.d);
                                }
                            });
                            }
                        }
                        xhr.send();
                    } else {
                        alert("Max File Size");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This is my backend code to save the file to the server

```
 public static string GetDriveFile(string FileName, string Base64)
    {
        try
        {
            string inputPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("UploadedFiles/") + FileName;
            byte[] image64 = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64);
            File.WriteAllBytes(inputPath, image64);
            return "true";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I'm using the base64 conversion from [here](https://gist.github.com/jonleighton/958841)

The Ajax POST method is not triggering and getting 500 internal server error as shown.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify where the issue lies, you can get the file content but can't connect to your backend?

Comment: I am able to get the base64 content and when trying to pass it through ajax call its not working as the base64 is not working on this website..I am using the same function for base64 conversion on another website and it is working fine. I am not sure why this isn't working here. I have added the link from where I'm using the base64 conversion 
https://gist.github.com/jonleighton/958841